# jQuery Animate plays backwards?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to use a fadein+slidedown script I found here on stackoverflow.

```
$('#topmenu').animate({
    "height": "toggle",
    "opacity": "toggle" 
}, "slow");

$('.post').delay(1000).animate({
    "height": "toggle", 
    "opacity": "toggle" 
}, "slow");
```

For some reason the two animations ARE PLAYING BACKWARDS [here](http://bit.ly/UQM7Ff)... can you help me figure the reason out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#topmenu` and `.post` need to be initially hidden to be able to fade in and slide down when using the `toggle` option. For example,

```
#topmenu, .post {
  display: none;
}
```

In your case, since the elements are initially visible, the `toggle` option will fade and slide them out.

You can also use `.hide()` before the animations. But, I still believe using CSS is the optimal solution here.

**Note:** You can make use of `"show"` and `"hide"` instead of `"toggle"` if you are applying a one-time effect.

Comment: @yckart all this works for slideDOWN. How do you slideUP instead?

Comment: @NiccolòMineo, what that question intended for me?

Comment: to both of you, Alexander (as I am commenting your post there is no need to manually mention you). Thank you!

Comment: @NiccolòMineo, I don't know what you are trying to achieve but you can use `"show"` and `"hide"` instead of `"toggle"` and I think it will fit your needs better. It seems you aren't making any use of `"toggle"` anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can Set your animations with custom values.

To hide:

```
$('#topmenu').animate({
    "height": 0
    "opacity": 0
}, "slow");

$('.post').delay(1000).animate({
    "height": 0,
    "opacity": 0
}, "slow");
```

To show:

```
$('#topmenu').animate({
    "height": $('#topmenu').outerHeight(),
    "opacity": 1
}, "slow");

$('.post').delay(1000).animate({
    "height": $('.post').outerHeight(),
    "opacity": 1
}, "slow");
```

Or you can Even use slideDown/slideUp and fadeIn/fadeOut.